# Scale and center image in each div in this container

Tags: html, css

I have this in HTML and i need the pictures inside the containers to be centered and to scale even if i resize the parent div

```
<div class="art-cont" id="art">
<div class="art-1">
<img src="https://cdn.stocksnap.io/img-thumbs/960w/2SQMYBPQGK.jpg">
</div>
<div class="art-2">
<img src="https://cdn.stocksnap.io/img-thumbs/960w/2SQMYBPQGK.jpg">
</div>
<div class="art-3">
<img src="https://cdn.stocksnap.io/img-thumbs/960w/2SQMYBPQGK.jpg">
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.art-cont{
    width:100%;
    height:400px;
}
.art-1{
    width:70%;
    height:50%;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:2px solid #fff;
}
.art-2{
    width:30%;
    height:50%;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:2px solid #fff;
}
.art-3{
    width:100%;
    height:50%;
    clear:both;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:2px solid #fff;
}
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0r7rhe77/

Answer (score 2):

The following rule will do it

```
.art-cont img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

as long as you're okay with [the browser compatibility of `object-fit`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit) (roughly 90% of users - most everybody except IE 11 or lower). Also check out [the other options for `object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit).

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tobek/5nfghxo2/1/)

---

Another option is refactoring your code to display the images using `background-image`, as all modern browsers support `background-size`. Remove the `<img>` elements and instead do:

```
.art-1, .art-2, .art-3 {
    background-image: url(https://cdn.stocksnap.io/img-thumbs/960w/2SQMYBPQGK.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

[Fiddle using this approach](https://jsfiddle.net/tobek/5nfghxo2/2/)